# SQL Stored procedure does not enter IF and CASE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which has a varchar input parameter. The body has several IF conditions which compare against this input parameter. Try as I may, it does not enter one of the IF conditions though everything seems to be fine. Any idea why this is happening?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetSnapshot] 
@ScenarioEnum varchar(10),
@LabelerCodes varchar(200) = null,
@StatusFilter varchar(200) = null
AS
BEGIN
IF(@ScenarioEnum = 'ManufacturerAdjudicationSnapshot')
    PRINT 'Inside the if statement'
END
IF(@ScenarioEnum = 'Works')
    PRINT 'Inside the 2ND if statement'
END
```

Comment: You only have 1 begin but 2 ends - might want to check the logic as well

Comment: The proc you posted will not compile.

Comment: That was the best statement. +1
Sorry but the SP was just a snippet with both ENDs in place.
Eventually i answered my own question. The problem was that the input parameter's length was too small to accomodate the value of the argument being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the length of the input parameter is too small.
Since the length of the argument passed was greater than the space reserved for the parameter, the input will be truncated to 'Manuf'
Increase the length reserved for ScenarioEnum parameter to an appropriate value and this will start working!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetSnapshot] 
@ScenarioEnum varchar(10),
@LabelerCodes varchar(200) = null,
@StatusFilter varchar(200) = null
AS
BEGIN
IF(@ScenarioEnum = 'ManufacturerAdjudicationSnapshot')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Inside the if statement'
END
ELSE IF(@ScenarioEnum = 'Works')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Inside the 2ND if statement'
END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove one `END`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetSnapshot] 
@ScenarioEnum varchar(10),
@LabelerCodes varchar(200) = null,
@StatusFilter varchar(200) = null
AS
BEGIN
IF(@ScenarioEnum = 'ManufacturerAdjudicationSnapshot')
    PRINT 'Inside the if statement'
IF(@ScenarioEnum = 'Works')
    PRINT 'Inside the 2ND if statement'
END
```